# Rewrite callback function with async series

Tags: node.js, express

I had this function:

```
exports.profileImage = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.user_id;
    userProvider.get(id, function(err, user){
        if (err) throw err;
        userProvider.getImageById(user['image_id'], function(err, image) {
            if (err) throw err;
            userProvider.writeImageToDisk(image, function(err, path){
                if (err) throw err;
                res.sendfile(path);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I rewrite it using local variables:

```
exports.profileImage = function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.user_id;
var userTemp = undefined;
var imageTemp = undefined;
async.series([
    userProvider.get(id, function(err, user){
        if (err) throw err;
        userTemp = user;
    }),
    userProvider.getImageById(userTemp['image_id'], function(err, image) {
        if (err) throw err;
        imageTemp = image;
    }),
    userProvider.writeImageToDisk(imageTemp, function(err, path){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.sendfile(path);
    })
]);}
```

I have a parameters which `userProvider.getImageById` (user json object) needs , it comes from `userProvider.get` function, Which invoked before, I save it to local variable.

I chose async to skip callback hell but it is not working.

**Error:**

```
Cannot read property 'image_id' of undefined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userTemp` is `undefined` at the point where you try to look up its `image_id`. It will only become not undefined when the previous asynchronous function has been called.

Answer (score 1):

Using [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall), you should be able to simplify your code considerably to something like (the untested);

```
var id = req.params.user_id;
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
       userProvider.get(id, callback);
    },
    function(user, callback) {
       userProvider.getImageById(user['image_id'], callback);
    },
    userProvider.writeImageToDisk,
    res.sendfile
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `async.series` works.

Each function in the array has to have the following signature:

```
function(callback) { ...; callback(...); };
```

Once the code for each function is done, you need to call the callback function to signal to `async` that it should run the next step ([docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)).

So your code should look like this:

```
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    userProvider.get(id, function(err, user) {
      if (err) throw err;
      userTemp = user;
      callback();
    });
  },
  function(callback) {
    userProvider.getImageById(userTemp['image_id'], function(err, image) {
      if (err) throw err;
      imageTemp = image;
      callback();
    });
  },
  function(callback) {
    userProvider.writeImageToDisk(imageTemp, function(err, path){
      if (err) throw err;
      res.sendfile(path);
      callback();
    });
  }
]);
```

Better yet, take a look at [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) for a way of passing results from one async function to the next.